# C++ cin.getline() causes program to crash

Tags: c++, cin

I'm making a simple encryption/decryption program... I'm a beginner.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char s[1025];
char o[1025];
char key[1025];

char tochar(int a)
{
    if(a<26) return 'a'+a;
    if(a>25 and a<52) return 'A'+a-26;
    if(a>51) return '0'+a-52;
}
int toint(char t)
{
    if(t>='a' and t<='z') return 0-'a'+t;
    if(t>='A' and t<='Z') return 26+t-'A';
    if(t>='0' and t<='9') return 52+t-'0';
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,keylenght;
    //for(j=0;j<62;j++)cout<<j<<" "<<tochar(j)<<" "<<toint(tochar(j))<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter String:\n";
    cin.getline(s,1024);
    cout<<"Function [encrypt/decrypt]: ";
    char f;
    cin>>f;
    if(f=='e')
    {
        cout<<"Generate key? [y/n]: ";
        cin>>f;
        if(f=='y')
        {
            cout<<"Enter key length [up to 1024]: ";
            cin>>keylenght;
            srand(time(0));
            for(i=0;i<keylenght;i++)
            {
                key[i]=tochar(rand()%62);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Enter key: \n";
            cin.getline(key,1024);
            for(keylenght=0;key[keylenght]!='\0';keylenght++);
        }

        for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
            if(key[keylenght%i]!=' ')
            {
                if(s[i]!=' ')o[i]=tochar((toint(s[i])+toint(key[i%keylenght]))%62);
                else o[i]=' ';
            }
            else
            {
                o[i]=s[i];
            }
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Encrypted string: "<<o<<endl<<"Generated key: "<<key;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Enter key: ";
        cin>>key;
        for(keylenght=0;key[keylenght]!='\0';keylenght++);
        for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
           if(s[i]!=' ')
           {
               if(key) o[i]=tochar((62+toint(s[i])-toint(key[i%keylenght]))%62);
           }
           else o[i]=' ';
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Decrypted string:\n"<<o;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first time I use getline() it works flawlessly. However when I try to use it to write in the key[] string, it crashes the program.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Comment: Line 51.
`cin.getline(key,1024);`

Comment: `if(key[keylenght%i]!=' ')` isn't going to work when `i` is zero (which it is in the very first iteration of the loop). An arithmetic exception for modulo-by-zero will ensue. I didn't really look at your getline suspects because that jumped out at me right off the bat. Pretty sure you wanted `i%keylength` there. After that, your `toint` function is dreadfully assumptive.

Comment: I tried adding a debug line `cout<<"getline dun";` after the cin.getline function.
This is what I get when i run the program. 
`Enter String:
test 1234
Function [encrypt/decrypt]: e
Generate key? [y/n]: n
Enter key:
getline dun`

Note that it didn't allow me to type anything. It seems like it just skipped the getline() function and went straight to the for loop, where it is logical for it to have crashed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing your input types.  When you call

```
cin>>f;
```

That leaves a newline in the input buffer.  Then on your call to getline() key only gets the newline.  What you need to do is clear the input buffer before you call getline.  I like to use:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `istream::getline()`, use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead. It is safer.